# How do I remove the lock on my tab

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

my question is in regards to the padlock in the google tab. How do I remove the lock?

[image]

With this lock on, I am unable to close the tab once it is opened. as you can see by the image I do not have any tab lock or any pinned tabs. I am not even sure how this happened.

Please help, this is just annoying.

Comment: The padblock isn't from stock Firefox, comes via an addon. What addons do you have installed?

Comment: There is a *Close tab* item in the menu visible on screenshot. What happens when you click it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe its an addon activated bu someone. Go in settings and look for addon. Check them, one of them should be the culprit. Then change the settings or remove it. ...

Comment: Sathya, the only addon I have is Tab Utilities 1.5.25.; gronostaj, as I stated I am unable to close that tab without closing firefox.

Comment: Remove it. Then try.Or if u can tweak the settings...